# Android App Access Control

Tags: android, security

I'm working on ADW.Launcher. I'm trying to implement access control, which will specify which apps can or cannot be started (e.g. forbidding the browser.)  Currently I can achieve  this by checking the package name before starting the activity.  However, if an app starts the browser directly:

e.g.

```
public class OpenBrowserTest extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setClassName("com.android.browser", 
                       "com.android.browser.BrowserActivity");
        startActivity(i);
    } 
}
```

my access control will be compromised.

Is there any way for the launcher to know whenever an activity is started?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way for the launcher to know whenever an activity is started ?

There are no broadcast `Intents` for this event.